# Maven not deploying test resources to embedded server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp, m2e

Eclipse Indigo, Tomcat 7, latest versions of Maven, WTP, and M2E/M2E-WTP plugins.

When Eclipse publishes my war to my local Tomcat server, it's not including src/test/resources. As a result it's not using my logback-test.xml and other test resources that I want to use in the context of local development. Is there any way to enable it to include these locally? I still want src/test/* to be excluded for the wars generated by "mvn install" that are deployed to production servers.

Comment: While i don't know the answer to this specific question, if you're interested in the configuration for something similar but using the Jetty Maven Plugin, let me know (i have Spring configuration files that i use for local development that need to override those in the main webapp and i keep them in the /src/test/resource folder)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify which directories/files, you want to include in the generated war file, in the  section from your POM file.

Feel free to take a look at this page : [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

Hope that'll help